# Getting documents from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pretty new to angular-firebase. So I'm getting a document from a collection, and it's working, but I don't understand how to display the data.

> (error: Cannot set property 'item' of undefined)

```
item: any;

constructor(....){}


db() {
  this.firestore.doc(`users/${this.id}`).ref.get().then(function (doc) {
      this.item = doc.data().name
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use the `this` keyword within a regular function (not a method of the class/component) which behaves differently than you are expecting. Instead of having a regular function like this:

```
this.firestore.doc(`users/${this.id}`).ref.get().then(function (doc) {
    this.item = doc.data().name
  });
}
```

You can use an ES6 arrow function like this.

```
this.firestore.doc(`users/${this.id}`).ref.get().then(doc => {
    this.item = doc.data().name
  });
}
```

For a better understanding of how the arrow ES6 function differ from regular functions, you can check out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) documentation.